# How to implement a member function once for both non-const and const overloads?

Tags: c++, constants

Sometimes I find myself adding overloads that have the same implementation, with `const` in qualifier and return value being the only difference:

```
struct B {};
struct A {
    const B& get(int key) const
    {
        if (auto i = map.find(key); i != map.end())
            return i->second;
        throw std::runtime_error{""};
    }

    B& get(int key)
    {
        if (auto i = map.find(key); i != map.end())
            return i->second;
        throw std::runtime_error{""};
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<int, B> map;
};
```

Is there an idiomatic way to write the implementation only once and get rid of copy-paste that is better than `const_cast`:

```
const B& get(int key) const
{
    return const_cast<A*>(this)->get(key);
}
```

?

Comment: Good question. Definitely a duplicate. An adequate pattern for this is yet to emerge. Scott Meyers uses the `const_cast` technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott Meyers' advice:

> When const and non-const member functions have essentially identical implementations, code duplication can be avoided by having the non-const version call the const version.

Comment: Not always feasible: `struct Counterexample { int meow() { return 42; } int meow() const { return 314; } int nyan() { return meow(); } int nyan() const { return meow(); } };`

Comment: Agree. But it may be useful in the OP context.

Comment: so it's essentially (almost) the same as my example with `const_cast`

Comment: Two casts are used. One is  a `static_cast` to add const to *this’s type, so that the const version will be called. and the other is `const_cast` to cast away `const` on the return type. And these casts are used in the non-const version.